# how to change woocommerce price style but only on single product page for the current product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hi I need to change the product price of the selected product on Woocommerce

i have this function

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_html', 11, 2 );

function custom_price_html($price_html, $product){
    if (is_product()) {

      // here I change the product price or styling
    }

}
```

the problem is that function executes on the product page... but also on the related products on the bottom of the page.

how can I identify only the CURRENT PRODUCT PRICE ?!

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an extra check in your if statement to avoid changing price html for the related products loop.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_html', 11, 2 );

    function custom_price_html($price_html, $product){

        global $woocommerce_loop;

        if( is_product() && !$woocommerce_loop['name'] == 'related' ) {
          // here I change the product price or styling
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: didnt work for me.. $woocommerce_loop['name'] returns empty string.

Comment: thanks. it was needed to specify the global variable

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot about the global variable. I'm adding that to my answer now. Thanks for pointing that out @MatiasAzar.